# Score in processing

Tags: processing

Hello I want to create a catch game in processing.
I added a score counter but it does not work properly.
When I catch the object I want the score to go up with 1.
If it touches the ground -5. The problem is that when it hit the ground the score still goes up with 1. anyone an idea? this is the class of the object:

```java
class Burger {

    int breedte;
    int hoogte;
    float snelheid;
    float x ;
    float y;

    Burger() {
        x = random(0,1000);
    }

    void run() {
        display();
        testBurger();
    }

    void display() {
        img1.resize(60,60);
        image(img1,x,y);
    }

    void testBurger() {
        y = y+richting;

        if(y > 800){
            x = random(0,1000);
            println(score);
        } 

        if(y > 600 && mouseX -90 < x && mouseX +90 > x){
            score = score+1;
            y = -400;
            x  = random(0,1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you decreasing the score by 5?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I did not add it because it does not work. I thought something like if(y == 800){ score = score-5;} but that does not work.

Comment: What is the value of richting each frame? What is the value of y each frame?

Comment: @DutchMasters On witch value do you initialize `y` and `richting`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of "magic numbers" in this code (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29 for why this is poor practice) but if I'm following correctly, then I think you have your signs the wrong way around.

You currently test `if(y > 800){` which would mean that that Burger object is near the bottom of the screen (remember, y-axis starts from 0 at the TOP of screen). I suggest you rather test `if (y < 800)` for the "catching" condition, and then you can simply use `} else {` at the end for the "hit the bottom of the screen" condition.